# API Calls connecting to intranet server not working in Android Emulator

Tags: android, rest, android-emulator, local, http-status-code-503

I am trying to connect to the local intranet server from my android application. The api calls work fine in the postman and other clients. But, when I am trying to do the get or post request to the server from android emulator, it's returning response code "503" (meaning host is not reachable).

The APIs are hosted in the server system which is in the local network. I have tried adding proxy, DNS settings, still no use.

I am stuck on this issue since a week now.

It would be great if someone could help on this!

Comment: Use 10.0.2.2 for default emulator and 10.0.3.2 for Genymotion. Use portNo respectively.

Comment: HTTP response code `500` means internal server error.

Comment: @KNeerajLal sorry my bad. It is 503

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay in emulator settings, I have already given the same long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set URL as `10.0.2.2:portNr`

`portNr` = the given port by ASP.NET Development Server

Comment: 10.0.2.2:portNr is used in the URL if it is connecting to local machine when your system is the server system right ?